# How to make a regex match with grep in shell script?

Tags: shell, grep

I am trying to create a shell script that matches a string with a predefined regex. I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
name="Name of string to match. #123"

(echo "$name" | grep -Eq  ^[#]\d+$) && echo "matched" || echo "did not 
match"
```

I am always getting a "did not match" message, even though I think the string in the example should match the regex. Can anyone realize what I am doing wrong? Is the regex wrong or is it the call to grep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the regex in quotes:

```
(echo "$name" | grep -Eq '^[#]\d+$') && echo "matched" || echo "did not match"
```

If you expect the sample input to match, remove the start-of-input anchor `^`, ie use `'[#]\d+$'` as your regex (which would match anything *ending* in `#` then digits).

Comment: Thanks! That was it